# NAnt build issues with Mono

Tags: mono, nant

I am trying to build a Mono project using NAnt but I get the error listed below. I have tried altering the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH to include the path leading to the file: mono.pc but that does not seem to work.

```
Failed to initialize the 'Mono 3.5 Profile' (mono-3.5) target framework.:
NAnt.Core.BuildException: Failed to initialize the 'Mono 3.5 Profile' (mono-3.5) target framework. ---> Unable to locate 'mono' module using pkg-config. Download the Mono development packages from http://www.mono-project.com/downloads/.:
NAnt.Core.BuildException: Unable to locate 'mono' module using pkg-config. Download the Mono development packages from http://www.mono-project.com/downloads/.
  at NAnt.Core.Tasks.FailTask.ExecuteTask () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NAnt.Core.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at NAnt.Core.FrameworkInfo.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NAnt.Core.FrameworkInfo.Validate () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NAnt.Core.ProjectSettingsLoader.ConfigureRuntimeFramework () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've recently had the same problem trying to install the [TAO Framework](http://sourceforge.net/projects/taoframework/) on Mac OSX 10.6.5 under Mono 2.8.1 with Nant 0.90 (FYI). Here's how I was led to solve this (guided by [this page](http://zzamboni.org/brt/2008/01/31/opensim-on-osx-or-your-own-secondlife-grid-in-8-easy-steps/)):

1. Locate the nant script itself ('/usr/bin/nant' on OSX, try 'which nant')
2. Open the 'nant' script in an editor (you might need the right permissions).
3. On a new line and **before** the 'exec ...' line, add something like:

   > export
   >   PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/Mono/Framework/Versions/VERSION/lib/pkgconfig

my Mac OSX version looks like:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/pkgconfig/
```

(nb. my version actually has 2 pkgconfig paths, separated by a colon ':', '/usr/lib/pkgconfig' is also searched automatically, JFYI).

Also, you should add the exact same 'export' line to one of your .bashrc or .profile files (or the corresponding /etc/bashrc or /etc/profile files to set this globally).

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Rich

Answer (score 3):

For me adding '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin' to the PATH has solved the issue on Mac OS X 10.7.3 with Mono 2.10.9 and NAnt 0.91.

Comment: Thank you! 6+ years after this answer was posted it saved my day (night :)